# Creation of a Logic App to Read an entry in database

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I would like to know whether a Logic App in Azure can be created to Read an entry in database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are connectors for several databases. Assuming it's a SQL Server:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure

Then just use "Add a SQL Action"

[image]